# Oracle case statement on a select

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to use a conditional on a select statement using it's columns. How can I write something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM ( CASE (SELECT date_term, e_status 
                             FROM HM
                             WHERE c_num = 2327
                               AND e_unique = 'something')
                       WHEN (date_term) < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                               OR (e_status IS NOT NULL OR e_status <> 'A')
                       THEN (SELECT NULL AS A,
                                    NULL AS B,
                                    NULL AS C,
                                    NULL AS D,
                                    NULL AS E,
                                    NULL AS F
                             FROM DUAL)
                       ELSE (SELECT p_val, p_type
                             FROM I_PARM T
                             WHERE c_num=2327
                             )
                             PIVOT 
                             (
                             MIN(p_val)
                             FOR p_type IN ('A1' AS A,
                                                    'B2' AS B,
                                                    'C3' AS C,
                                                    'D4' AS D,
                                                    'E5' AS E,
                                                    'F6' AS F)
                                                    )
                END);
```

- **UPDATE** The whole query is a bit more complicated than my original one.

I'm getting a missing right parenthesis error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT case when x.a = 'something' then b.y
       else c.z end
FROM X JOIN Y on x.somecol = y.somecol
JOIN Z on x.somecol = z.somecol;
```

The way you had it in the question is an incorrect use of case. Replace the `join` conditions with appropriate column names, as you seem to pick up values from different tables.

Comment: You can also use `CASE x.a WHEN 'something' THEN`, but you can't have both a value following the `CASE` and a comparison after the when.